# how to count how many iterations it takes to get a random number equal to user input and calculate that average in C?

Tags: c, random, nested-loops

Using nested loops, We have to create a program that takes a number in range of 0-99 from the user and use a seeded random number generator to try and guess the number. We have to keep track of how many numbers the RNG generates before it generates the user's number. We have to also do this process 50 times to then calculate the average number of tries it takes the RNG to guess our number. 
This is all i have so far and i'm stumped:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    int userInput;
    int randoms = rand() % 100;
    int numCalls;
    int i;
    float average = 0.0;

    printf("Please enter a number in between 0 and 99: ");
    scanf(" %d", &userInput);

    for( i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {

        while (userInput != randoms);
        {

           numCalls = numCalls + 1;

           if (userInput = randoms)
           {
               float average = numCalls/50.0;

           }
        }
        printf("Number of iterations it took for a matching number: %d\n", numCalls);
        printf("Average number of iterations to find a match: %.2f\n", average);

    }

return;
}
```

Comment: `int numCalls;` --> `int numCalls = 0;`, `if (userInput = randoms)` --> `if (userInput == randoms)`, `float average = numCalls/50.0;` --> `average = numCalls/50.0;` and Need re-input `userInput`.

Comment: You should be able to find out why your program is not working as you want it to with simple `printf`-debuging. Add statements like `printf("Value of average: %f\n", average);` and you will see values and maybe find the errors in your code.

Comment: Also `average = numCalls/50.0;` inside the loop is unnecessary, you need only sum the total attempts through the 50 iterations and then take the average after.

Comment: Also `return;` --> `return 0;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There are no update of `randoms` value
2. `if (userInput=randoms)` is not a boolean function, it should be `if (userInput==randoms)` instead

Here's what I suggest:

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    int userInput;
    int randoms = rand() % 100;
    int numCalls;
    int i;
    float average = 0.0;

    int totalCalls=0;

    printf("Please enter a number in between 0 and 99: ");
    scanf(" %d", &userInput);

    for( i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        numCalls = 0; //reset iteration number
        do{
            randoms = rand()%100;
            numCalls++
        } while (randoms!=userInput);

        totalCalls += numCalls;         
        printf("Number of iterations it took for a matching number: %d\n", numCalls);
        average = (float)totalCalls/(float)i;
        printf("Average number of iterations to find a match: %.2f\n", average);
    }

return;
}
```

Comment: It would be even better with `if (scanf(" %d", &userInput) != 1) { /* handle error */ }` to prevent *Undefined Behavior* if the user entered, e.g. `ten` and you then used the uninitialized `userInput` over and over again inside a loop...

Answer (score 0):

Here, you are taking 1 input from user, and just calculating the number of RNG calls required for that input. Dividing this number by 50 won't give you the average.

You want to take the input 50 times, i.e., the scanf statement should be inside the loop.
If numCalls[i] is the number of random number generator calls required for ith input, average is the summation for all the 50 inputs divided by 50.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the technical failure to update `randoms` and the *equality* comparison, you must *validate* ALL user input, and *validate* the value provided is within your expected range. Otherwise, you risk invoking *Undefined Behavior* if a *matching* or *input* failure occurs.

`scanf` has a **return**. You must use it to validate the successful conversion for each of the *conversion specifiers* contained within your *format string* (e.g `"%d"` is `1` conversion). If a successful conversion is performed, then you must validate that the value is between `0 - 99`. You can accomplish that with:

```
#define MAXN   99
...
    if (scanf ("%d", &num) != 1) {  /* validate ALL user input */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (num < 0 || num > MAXN) {    /* validate num is within range */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: value out of range: %d\n", num);
        return 1;
    }
```

Think about the scope within which your variables are needed. Yes you can declare them all up top, but if they are only used within a loop, etc.., you reduce the chance of a name collision or inadvertent later modification of a value if you declare the values within the scope they are needed. (and with C99 or later, you can declare you `for` loop variable within the loop declaration (e.g. `for (int i = 0; ...)`)

Putting those pieces together, you can protect against UB by validating your input, as above, and tidy the scope of your variable declarations with something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NTIMES 50   /* if you need a constant, declare one (or two) */
#define MAXN   99

int main (void) {

    int i, num;
    double avg = 0.0;

    srand (time (NULL));

    printf ("enter a number (0-%d): ", MAXN);
    if (scanf ("%d", &num) != 1) {  /* validate ALL user input */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (num < 0 || num > MAXN) {    /* validate num is within range */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: value out of range: %d\n", num);
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < NTIMES; i++) {  /* loop 50 time for average */
        int nrands = 0,
            randnum = rand() % (MAXN + 1);    /* get 1st random */
        /* loop until equal updating counter nrands */
        for (; randnum != num; randnum = rand() % (MAXN + 1))
            nrands += 1;
        printf ("test[%2d] : %4d iterations to match.\n", i+1, nrands); 
        avg += nrands;      /* keep sum in avg */
    }
    avg /= (double)NTIMES;  /* divide for final average */

    printf ("\nAverage number of iterations to find match: %.2f\n", avg);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/iters2match
enter a number (0-99): 31
test[ 1] :   19 iterations to match.
test[ 2] :   30 iterations to match.
test[ 3] :  239 iterations to match.
test[ 4] :  116 iterations to match.
test[ 5] :  220 iterations to match.
test[ 6] :  198 iterations to match.
test[ 7] :   64 iterations to match.
test[ 8] :   77 iterations to match.
test[ 9] :  106 iterations to match.
test[10] :   94 iterations to match.
test[11] :  123 iterations to match.
test[12] :   77 iterations to match.
test[13] :  167 iterations to match.
test[14] :   23 iterations to match.
test[15] :    3 iterations to match.
test[16] :  226 iterations to match.
test[17] :   58 iterations to match.
test[18] :  190 iterations to match.
test[19] :   44 iterations to match.
test[20] :  204 iterations to match.
test[21] :  134 iterations to match.
test[22] :   30 iterations to match.
test[23] :   40 iterations to match.
test[24] :   59 iterations to match.
test[25] :   21 iterations to match.
test[26] :  218 iterations to match.
test[27] :    8 iterations to match.
test[28] :   21 iterations to match.
test[29] :  259 iterations to match.
test[30] :  227 iterations to match.
test[31] :   11 iterations to match.
test[32] :   22 iterations to match.
test[33] :  187 iterations to match.
test[34] :   90 iterations to match.
test[35] :    5 iterations to match.
test[36] :   43 iterations to match.
test[37] :  114 iterations to match.
test[38] :   38 iterations to match.
test[39] :   24 iterations to match.
test[40] :   53 iterations to match.
test[41] :   71 iterations to match.
test[42] :  148 iterations to match.
test[43] :   61 iterations to match.
test[44] :   78 iterations to match.
test[45] :    5 iterations to match.
test[46] :   30 iterations to match.
test[47] :  281 iterations to match.
test[48] :   18 iterations to match.
test[49] :  109 iterations to match.
test[50] :   31 iterations to match.

Average number of iterations to find match: 94.28
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.